# Insert data related two table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I get null result in city but data save, and when insert i insert data `city_id` and in query insert `city_id` was null, can you help me? thanks

this is my model :

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
    }
```

and **City model** :

```
class City extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Company::class);
    }
```

and my **controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $company_name = $request->input('name');
        $city_name = $request->input('city_id');
        $company_address = $request->input('address');

        $data = new \App\Models\Company();
        $data->name = $company_name;
        $data->address = $company_address;
        $data->city_id = $city_name;
       // $data->save();
        $city = new \App\Models\City();
        //$data->companies->add($data);
        $data->city()->associate($city->city_id);
        $data->save();

        if($data->save()){
            $res['message'] = "Success!";
            $res['value'] = "$data";
            //return response($res);
            return redirect('/companies')->with('success', 'Data has been added');
        }else{
            $res['message'] = "Not Success!";
            $res['value'] = "$data";
            return response($res);
        }
```

and the result :

```
    {
      "id": 6,
      "city_id": null,
      "name": "aaa",
      "address": "bbb",
      "created_at": "2019-03-16 23:45:49",
      "updated_at": "2019-03-16 23:45:49",
      "deleted_at": null,
      "city": null
    },

and the form:
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/branches') }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cityname" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><i class="fa fa-building"> &nbsp;</i>Company Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <select class="form-control" name="company_id" id="company_id" style="width: 100%;">
                       <option selected="selected">Company Name : </option>
                            @if (count($company) > 0)
                                 @for($i = 0; $i < count($company); $i++)
                                 <option value="{{ $company[$i]->company_id }}">{{ $company[$i]['name']  }}</option>
                                 @endfor
                            @endif
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Branch Name :</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="address">Address : </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="address"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cityname" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><i class="fa fa-building"> &nbsp;</i>City</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                       <select class="form-control" name="city_id" id="city_id" style="width: 100%;">
                       <option selected="selected">Pilih Kota : </option>
                            @if (count($city) > 0)
                                 @for($i = 0; $i < count($city); $i++)
                                 <option value="{{ $city[$i]->city_id }}">{{ $city[$i]['name']  }}</option>
                                 @endfor
                            @endif
                        </select>
                    </div>
            </div>         
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: can you show us your form?

Comment: I believe your select is wrong, are you receiving the city_id in your request? use ```dd($request->city_id)``` and show us what you get, please. Also, where this $city variable come from? could you show us the function?

Comment: No i cant get request, city_id is null

Comment: The problem is in your select then, i will write a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your select is wrong, first of all, in your controller function you should send the cities to this page like this:

```
$cities = City::all()
return view('your-view', compact('cities'));
```

Then you can loop the `$cities` variable in the select and make a option for each city:

```
<select class="form-control" name="company_id" id="company_id" style="width: 100%;">
    @foreach($cities as $city)
    <option value="{{$city->id}}">{{$city->name}} </option>  
    @endforeach
</select>
```

In your store function you could do this:

```
$data->city_id = $request->city_id;
$data->save();
```